# JPA Testing framework

Tags: spring, jpa

My application uses JPA (1.2), Spring (3.1.2), Spring Data (1.1.0) and Hibernate (4.1.7).

We need to write the Junit testcases for test the Entity and Repository but we are not able to found correct example for Junit and framwork which is correct to test all the scenrio of JPA.

Please let us know whic framework is correct for writing the Junit for JPA repositary and entity.

Comment: JPA1.2 doesn't exist. 1.0? 2.0? 2.1?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Spring Test framework which gives the developers the ability to bootstrap the dependency injection container with the test.  You can then autowire your repositories into a test.

Here is an excerpt test that I have used the framework for:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:META-INF/spring/test-context.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=false)
public class CommentRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private CommentRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    PostRepository postRepository;

    @Test
    public void findOneTest(){
       Comment comment= repository.findOne(1);
       assertNotNull(comment);
       assertEquals("John Doe", comment.getAuthor());
    }

}
```

Notice how the `@ContextConfiguration` points to a Spring Beans Configuration file.  Thats the dependency injection container being bootstrapped.  The `@Autowired` annotations are injecting my repositories for testing.  The `@TransactionConfiguration` tells Spring not to rollback the test so you can run your unit tests against a sandbox database, this can expose issues that the rollback functionality hides.

I have a project which demonstrates the configuration for this on [GitHub](https://github.com/kmb385/ToThoughtDataLayer).

I have also created a video tutorial demonstrating how to [configure jUnit tests with Spring Test](http://tothought.cloudfoundry.com/post/3).

I also have an example of a [test](https://github.com/kmb385/ToThoughtDataLayer/blob/master/src/test/java/org/tothought/repositories/SkillRepositoryTest.java) using the `@Transactional` annotation.

Comment: Each test function has its own transaction so i need to test all thing in one function only that is not correct. If you have any example then please provide me that link

Comment: @RanuJain So your saying test will be `@Transactional`, maybe persisting multiple entities?

Comment: Yes...and we already write Junit classes with SpringJunit but its not giving proper result. Some where we have dependency of other entity then on test everything works fine but in actual when we try to save its throwing error.Because in test its not inserted the data in DB actually because of @Transaction.

Comment: @RanuJain Setup a garbage schema just for unit testing, then annotate the test with `@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=false)` to commit the transaction.

Comment: Thanks for help. But in you test classes you are deppending on Data and in your Junit you actually do the operation on real data which we dont want so for that we used DBunit too.. But still we are not able to test all the mapping through test. How we will achive that.... We try EasyMock to..

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the simple POC project I'm working currently:

https://github.com/ndjordjevic/dental-rec

You can find there some ideas how to test jpa entities with jpa, spring, junit, dbunit etc ...